# how to take the Emojicons and Gallery images into the EditText Box

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-bitmap

In my application I am using below project link,In this application extra I want to add the Gallery images into the Edit Text.I need to add Gallery button extra and if we click the Gallery button,I want to appear the gallery page in that SD card I want to select the any image and put the images in Edit Text field like an emoticons,In that case where ever we can add the gallery images into the Edit Text field, If there is any possible to add the Gallery images into the Edit Text.

https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: you may need to create your own view for this. EditText can only have images on the top, left, bottom, and right (using setCompoundDrawable method)

Comment: How can i do this can you give any idea i did use this setCompoundDrawable method.

Comment: I have tried the code for image getter method but its not working for me would give some idea.

Comment: I have completed the task thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Pans how did you complete this task using this library? Please tell me.Thanks in advance.